# Trying to add pull to refresh in Swift 4 but getting an error

Tags: ios, swift, pull-to-refresh

I need help fixing this issue! I am adding pull to refresh to my table view. When I pull to refresh I want the articles to refresh. If someone who knows this would help me would be great, and if there is anything else wrong too.

```
Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer
```

The error is here:

```
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(fetchArticles(fromSource: source)), for: .valueChanged)
    return refreshControl
}()
```

Here is the function `fetchArticles`:

```
@objc func fetchArticles(fromSource provider: String){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Something seems to be wrong with the formatting. Can you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add another function to refresh articles, because you are passing a parameter:

```
@objc func refreshArticles() {
    self.fetchArticles(fromSource: self.source))
}
```

And addTarget like this:

```
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshArticles), for: .valueChanged)
```

Also, Do not miss to add refreshControl to tableView, as such:

```
tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
```

**Update** Add following line once fetchArticles completes, as such:

```
refreshControl.endRefreshing()
```

You are using `session.dataTask` so this must go inside:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I can only refresh once, how do I fix that?

Comment: Please check **Update** section of my answer, after this you will be able to refresh again

Comment: I added this and it worked thanks:                                                       
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.refresher.endRefreshing()
        }